# Using Jquery + Timepiker "From" time can't greater than "To" time?

Tags: jquery

Html content for From and To time:

```
<div class="elementbox">
   <label class="form-label">Select Time</label>
      <div class="controls">
           From <input type="text" id="from_t" name="from_t"/> 
           To <input type="text" id="to_t" name="to_t"/>  
     </div>
</div>
```

Jquery For Both input text

```
$('#from_t').timepicker();
$('#to_t').timepicker();
```

I tried to solve it but it's not work properly. so, please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Which time picker you are using?
Bootstrap time picker, jQuery UI time picker, or something else?

If you are using jquery UI time picker, you can use the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/FdfPY/1/

```
$(".from_date").datepicker({
    minDate: 'D',
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
        $(".to_date").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        $(this).parent().next().children().focus();
    }
});
$(".to_date").datepicker({
    minDate: '+1D',
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    numberOfMonths: 2
});
```

Comment: Jquery UI Timepiker,

Comment: Thank You sir,
but it is for DatePiker i want to work with only TimePiker.

Comment: use javascript validation